# Write a Python code that replaces all the integers of the list below, including integers inside sublists, with their squared values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

I want to square the values within this list, but I keep getting [1, 3, [0, 10], 8, 9, [13]] as my output.

This is my code:

```
new_list = [1,3, [0,10], 8, 9, [13]]
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    if type(new_list[i]) == int:
        new_list[i] == (new_list[i] ** 2)
    else:
        nested_list1 = new_list[2]
        nested_list2 = new_list[5]
        for i in range(len(nested_list1)):
            nested_list1[i] == (nested_list1[i] ** 2)
        for i in range(len(nested_list2)):
            nested_list2[i] == (nested_list2[i] ** 2)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typos in your code. You have `==` where you mean `=`.

Also your code keeps on squaring the nested lists more times than it means.

You meant to write this code:

```
new_list = [1, 3, [0, 10], 8, 9, [13]]
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    if type(new_list[i]) == int:
        new_list[i] = (new_list[i] ** 2)
    else:
        nested_list = new_list[i]
        for i in range(len(nested_list)):
            nested_list[i] = (nested_list[i] ** 2)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, [0, 100], 64, 81, [169]]
```